# Cosmos DB Faulting But Does Write

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am getting a weird issue when writing to Cosmos DB. The first write seems to fail with a `ResultCode` of `Faulted`. However, it seems like the write actually did work and when it retries the `ResultCode` is a `409` Conflict.

[image]

This is a problem as I am using this as an idempotent check so we subsequently don't perform a third party call.

[image]

Any ideas why we get this behaviour? It seems like we need to turn off a setting / option to prevent it from retrying.

We have a fairly simple setup of the document client

```
return new DocumentClient(new Uri(configuration["CosmosDBSettings:EndpointUri"]), configuration["CosmosDBSettings:AuthenticationKey"]);
```

The code to insert the document is:

```
public async Task<bool> TryInsertReference(Guid paymentReference)
{
    try
    {
        await this.documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, VoidCollectionId), new Payment { PaymentReference = paymentReference });
        return true;
    }
    catch (DocumentClientException e) when (e.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
    
public async Task Initialise()
{
    await CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync();
    await this.CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(GuaranteeCollectionId);
    await this.CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(VoidCollectionId);
}

private async Task CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await documentClient.ReadDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(DatabaseId));
    }
    catch (DocumentClientException e)
    {
        if (e.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            await documentClient.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = DatabaseId });
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

private async Task CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(string collectionId)
{
    try
    {
        await documentClient.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, collectionId));
    }
    catch (DocumentClientException e)
    {
        if (e.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            await documentClient.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(DatabaseId), new DocumentCollection { Id = collectionId, DefaultTimeToLive = this.timeToLive });
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include actual error content and relevant code?

Comment: What happens on the "Faulted" event? What error are you getting or why do you consider it Faulted?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I am seeing this in application insights whether thats the cosmos client doing that I am not sure

Comment: Conflict(409) is expected when you send a Create operation for an "id" that already exists or you are violating a [Unique Key contraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys). Without details of what that "Faulted" is or what is the error, no idea how to help.

Comment: How can the first write fail when the document didn't exist? Look at the logs, the second one results in a 409. The first one apparently failed but did commit.